# Parsing JSON using Swift

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift, tableview

I have an async method in a custom class that returns an NSArray containing dictionaries. I am trying to display this data in a UITableView. One issue is that the getGenres method call is async so the data gets loaded after the table is displayed. The main problem is figuring out how to implement the 3 datasource methods. In Objective C this was so simple...

```
var genreList:NSArray?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Bookshop.getGenres {
        genres in
            self.genreList = genres // copies data to the public NSArray
            self.tableView.reloadData() // this returns the data async so need to reload the tableview
            println("records: \(self.genreList?.count)") // displays the array of dictionaries correctly
    }
}

// #pragma mark - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.genreList != nil {
        println("Rows in section: \(self.genreList?.objectAtIndex(0))")
        return self.genreList?.count! // Value of optional 'Int?' not wrapped; did you mean to use '!' 
    }
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GenreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = "Hello World!"
    println("ROW: \(indexPath.row)")
    println("data: \(self.genreList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))")
    var item = self.genreList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) Variable 'item' inferred to have type 'AnyObject?', which may be unexpected.
    //cell.textLabel.text = item.title
    //var item:NSDictionary = self.genreList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary
    //println("item: \(item)")
    return cell
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems so unnecessarily complicated to do what is a really simple task.

This is my utility class:

```
import Foundation

class Bookshop {
    class func getGenres(completionHandler: (genres: NSArray) -> ()) {
        //println("Hello inside getGenres")
        let urlPath = "http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~bookshop/v1.1/index.php/genre/list"
        //println(urlPath)
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var resultsArray:NSArray!
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            data, response, error in
            //println("Task completed")
            if(error) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            //println("no error")
            var err: NSError?
            var options:NSJSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: options, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if(err != nil) {
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            //NSLog("jsonResults %@", jsonResult)
            let results: NSArray = jsonResult["genres"] as NSArray
            //NSLog("jsonResults %@", results)
            //resultsArray = results
            //println("calling completion handler")
            completionHandler(genres: results)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having? (Also, I don't see anything about JSON parsing in your question -- while you're editing it to make it more answerable, you might consider changing the title to something more descriptive.)

Comment: I can't extract the number of indexes in the NSArray self.genreList.count gives me the error Value of optional 'Int?' not wrapped; did you mean to use '!' and the line var item = ... give me a warning Variable 'item' inferred to have type 'AnyObject?', which may be unexpected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What swift has done is just eliminating a bunch of error-prone functionality we really shouldn't have been depending on anyway, specifically relying on messages set to zero was always error prone.  Now it's a little bit more verbose, but significantly more explicit, and hence safe.

The equivalent of `return self.genreList.count` in objective-C is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let genres = self.genreList {
        return genres.count
    }
    else {
        // Note: this is the case when you haven't yet downloaded your genre
        //  list, do whatever is appropriate, this just shows an empty list
        return 0
    }
}
```

Since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only be called if you have a non-zero cell count, that method is simpler, but really for consistency/safety, you follow the same general flow:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    if let genres = self.genreList as? [NSDictionary] {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GenreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var item = genres[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = item["title"] as String
        return cell
    }
    else {
        // Note: again, this is the case where you don't have your genre list
        //  list yet, so you can create whatever default cells needed.
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: The rationale here is spot-on: introducing more implicitly unwrapped optionals makes your code less readable and more error-prone, when what you really need is to check the optionals you already have. Also, you can shorten the first case using the optional coalescing operator introduced in beta 5, reducing the `numberOfRowsInSection` body to a single line: `return self.genreList?.count ?? 0`

Comment: Yeah, the coalescing operator is a more concise way of expressing it.  In this case I was more trying to establish a general pattern of how to effectively and clearly handle optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration of self.genreList from `var genreList:NSArray?` to `var genreList:NSArray!`. Then you can access the members like you did it in Obj-C (without the quesitonmark). And maybe, if the handler from the getGenres-method is in another thread you need to write

```
Bookshop.getGenres {
        genres in
            self.genreList = genres // copies data to the public NSArray
dispath_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
            self.tableView.reloadData() // this returns the data async so need to reload the tableview
            println("records: \(self.genreList.count)") // displays the array of dictionaries correctly
}
    }
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you need to cast the item like this:

```
var item = self.genreList[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
dump(item) // just to show the dictionary in this scenario
cell.textLabel.text = item["title"] as String
```

ALSO: you have to check if self.genreList != nil before accessing it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if genreList != nil {
var item = self.genreList[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    dump(item) // just to show the dictionary in this scenario
    cell.textLabel.text = item["title"] as String
}
else {
cell.textLabel.text = "Loading..."
}
```

Comment: Ben, your first correction was perfect but the last bit won't work because each index contains a dictionary which looks like this: {
    id = 9;
    records = 2;
    selfLink = "http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~bookshop/v1.1/index.php/genre/id/9";
    title = "Food and Drink";
} rather then being an instance of a myGenre object. I was trying to retrieve the dictionary at the appropriate index then extract each string and int to display in the table view cell.

Comment: The first line var item gives the error 'AnyObject' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'

Comment: That's weird, what about using the NSDictionary? I also changed the code to look cooler :)

Comment: no errors in syntax but crashes on that line with error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: So in your getGenres-method, what exactly is the type if genres? (Just alt-click on that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58991/discussion-between-benjamin-herzog-and-user303229).

Comment: "Change your declaration of `self.genreList` from `var genreList:NSArray?` to `var genreList:NSArray!`" -- that is, using an _implicitly unwrapped optional_, cannot be a general advice. Specifically, in the OPs scenario using an explicitly unwrapped optional is the better approach IMO. See also "Optionals" in [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)